# Как теперь работать с объектом переданным по ссылке в данном случае?

Tags: c++, указатели

наследник получает от класса родителя при вызове функции ссылку на стек родителя. Мне нужно всего то взять с него содержимое, как будет грамотно указать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам прямо компилятор говорит, может использовать `->` ?

Comment: stack->pop() или поставить скобки  (*stack).pop()

Comment: в данном случае объект передается по указателю

Comment: @KoVadim компилятор то предлагает, но вопроса знак указателя не решает. Да и IDE отказывается автоматом точку заменять на стрелку. В таком случае пишет: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'QStack<object *>'
    object* TempObj = *stack->pop();
                                           ^

Comment: У точки приоритет намного сильнее, чем у звёздочки. Так-что скобки нужны.

Comment: @AlexGlebe так ничего ж не меняется со скобками и точками. Все та же:  implicit instantiation of undefined template 'QStack<object *>'
    object* TempObj = *stack->pop();
                                             ^

Comment: тогда приводите полный пример кода. Будем фиксить.

Comment: @KoVadim да вот не знаю что можно в качестве полного примера скинуть, все данные классу же знакомы

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
object *TempObj = stack->pop();
```

Comment: Не работает. Выкидывает: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'QStack<object *>'
    object *TempObj = stack->pop();
                                           ^

Comment: Может Вы забыли подключить QStack ?? типа `#include <QStack>` ??

Comment: А тут уже смотрите, что не подключили. Видит ли линковщик библиотеку QStack или нет.

Comment: упс, точно. Рассчитывал что в хедере подключен